# error while plotting hist plot for a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, plot, bar-chart, visualization

I have a data that look like this:

```
cis_distance_freq4
# A tibble: 6 × 2
  distance  freq
     <dbl> <dbl>
1        0    NA
2     1000  4380
3    10000  4381
4    40000  4535
5    80000  4536
6  1000000  4558

hist(cis_distance$freq)
```

I want to plot in such a way that x axis is distance and y axis is freq.
Does anyone know how to plot this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in base R using the formula `~` notation in `barplot`:

```
barplot(freq ~ distance, data = cis_distance_freq4, 
        ylim = c(0, 5000),
        xlab = "Distance", ylab = "Frequency")
```

[image]

Or in the popular `ggplot2`:

```
ggplot(cis_distance_freq4[-1,], aes(x = as.factor(distance), y = freq)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  ylim(c(0,5000)) +
  ylab("Distance") + xlab("Frequency")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's the `ggplot()` solution, using `geom_bar()` with `stat="identity"`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
cis_distance_freq4 <- tibble::tribble(
~distance,  ~freq,
      0,    NA,
   1000,  4380,
  10000,  4381,
  40000,  4535,
  80000,  4536,
1000000,  4558)


ggplot(cis_distance_freq4, aes(x=as.factor(distance), y=freq)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=.99)
#> Warning: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (`position_stack()`).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>